# A Java Server side (Jsp, velocity, whatever) Calendar component?

Tags: java, jsp, calendar, velocity

Do you know of a Java Server side calendar component.
Not a date picker, but a way to display months or weeks as in google calendar with events from my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of sourceforge brings up [Jwebcalendar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcwebcalendar/).

> "JWebCalendar is a multilanguage Java JSP/Servlet webapplication. It's intended to provide a Webbased Group Calendar, supporting multiple Users. Users can manage their appointments, invite other users , get email notifications, view other users's calendar"